# Why was this comment flag (on a triplicated comment) declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

This is the declined flag:

[image: screenshot]

This was the comment I flagged:

[image: screenshot 2]

Why was this flagged declined with no comment? Does there really have to be three comments that say exactly the same thing? (In fact, I think "why downvote" comments shouldn't exist at *all*, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: A pointer to [the question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19914/implement-a-useless-interpreter) would have been helpful.

Comment: Hi, it is very frustrating to get downvotes from nowhere for no reason, this behaviour drives people away from this site. When I got the first downvote, I posted the comment in hope that the downvoter could explain why, but nope. Then there was a second downvote, I did the same, but nope. If there was something wrong with my question, I would really really like to know it to get some feedback and fix it. I think that if you are willing to downvote something, you should be polite enough to explain what is wrong (except if somebody else already did). Random downvoting for nothing is bad IMHO.

Comment: And by the way, I was trying to establish some dialog with whoever downvoted the question and incentive them to explain what is wrong in the question. Unfortunately, that is an exercise of futility.

Comment: @Victor That does sound completely reasonable, but you must realize that there's almost no way that these downvoters are going to come back and read the comments on a post they downvoted a while ago. These comments are just clutter, *especially* when there's three identical ones.

Comment: @Doorknob Sorry about that. OTOH you could just add a comment asking me to delete two of the comments and I would do that, and then there would be no need for flagging it.

Comment: @Victor And add yet another useless comment? ;-) In any case, there's no reason to bother you, and this is what flags are for in the first place.

Comment: Well, anyway there should be something wrong with the question. Got downvotes and just Timtech's answer other than myself. Even with a bounty nobody added some new answer, and it is an easy problem after all. BTW, if you think that you can beat Timtech's answer (and this should be easy), I will probably give the bounty to you.

Comment: @victor I did not like this question much as it was not a programming challenge, but rather "write a joke in the in the form of a program." However there are many questions here which are not to my taste which I simply ignore. I havent downvoted anyone yet. With this question you got it totally right and people produced some clever programming answers: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16226/15599 Regardless of what I thought of the question, thank you for posting. We need people to post questions. The overall vote score isnt that bad. Dont worry, you cant please all the people all the time.

Comment: There should've been a way for the poster to actually address the downvoters, like send them a message or something, and/or to notify them that the question was changed and maybe they would like to take back the downvote etc.

Comment: @daniero Indeed.

Answer (score 6):

My best guess is that the handling moderator misunderstood your text as meaning that this was your third flag, because I think the comments are definitely pointless. I regularly remove such comments.